# Insert filestream row to SQL Server in network using C#

Tags: c#

How to insert a very big file (> 4 GB) into SQL Server over network having filestream column?

I use the following code but it throws an exception in `ReadAllBytes` method on files bigger than 2GB. What is the solution?

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(fs);
byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName);
rdr.Close();
fs.Close();

MyDatabase.SPAddNewFile(fileData)
```

Comment: You need to use the **streaming** approach by means of the [`SqlFileStream` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to stream your data to SQL Server in manageable chunks - rather than loading the whole huge file into memory in a single operation ....

Comment: varbinary(max) columns are limited to 2Gb. So you can't insert so very big file